# Regex to validate multiple formats with optional pre and post strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate in the most efficient way 2 different ways to identify a location string, but either can have a slight variation and either can have a set of characters before and after the main string.

Valid values:

#### Number 1

```
14-36-085-17 W6
14-36-085-17-W6
14-36-085-17W6
```

#### Number 2

```
D 096 H 094A15
```

#### Number 3 either of those above can have 3 digits before and 2 digits after the main string (or not)

```
100 14-36-085-17W6 00
200 D 096 H 094A15 00
```

#### Of those 5 additional characters, these are the rules:

- 1st - always 1 or 2
- 2nd - always 0
- 3rd - 0 to 9
- 4th - always 0
- 5th - 0 to 9

So, it would be `[1-2]0[0-9]` and `0[0-9]` respectively, I think. Also note, the first 3 digits are dependent on the last 2 digits and vice versa. The first 3 digits can only be there if the last 2 digits are there, and the last 2 digits can only be there if the first 3 digits are there.

#### This gives us the following invalid strings which should NOT match:

```
100 14-36-085-17W6
14-36-085-17W6 00
```

#### Here's my code for the two main numbers

```
function func(s) 
{
  var re = /(^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}W\d$)|(^[A-D] [0-9]{3} [A-L] [0-9]{3}[A-P][0-9]{2}$)/;
  return re.test( s );
}
```

I'm only assuming use #3 of Case Number 1 for the first validation, because I'm not sure how to do space, dash or nothing as valid.

Comment: to do "space, dash, or nothing as valid", as you put it, `[ -]?` should work.

Comment: I updated your question based on your requirement in your comment to @SamuelReid's answer. If it's wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to be constructing a big regexp all in
one go. It will be hard to read and hard to maintain. And
your fellow developers will hate you when they have to debug
it while you are on holiday in Cancún sipping margaritas on
the beach.

So I'd recommend breaking it down into clear, meaningful
chunks (you'll have to use your judgement here: it's your
domain). Maybe something like this.

```
var prefix = '([12]0[0-9] )';
var suffix = '( 0[0-9])';
// ? optionally matches the preceding item.
// And don't forget to escape backslashes when creating
// a regexp from a string.
var num1 = '\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}[- ]?W\\d';
var num2 = '[A-D] [0-9]{3} [A-L] [0-9]{3}[A-P][0-9]{2}';
var numbers = '(' + num1 + '|' + num2 + ')';
var pattern = '^(' + prefix + numbers + suffix + '|' + numbers + ')$';
// Instead of creating a large regexp literal all in
// one go, you can build up the regexp pattern from strings,
// and then use RegExp(pattern) to make a regexp instance.
var rx = RegExp(pattern);
```

And now you can use `rx` to match against your input
numbers. Feel free to use more meaningful variable names.

But don't just leave it there. This code is crying out for
some tests.

```
var testcases = [
    {
        name: 'Number 1',
        tests: [
            {input: '14-36-085-17 W6', expected: true},
            {input: '14-36-085-17-W6', expected: true},
            {input: '14-36-085-17W6', expected: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Number 2',
        tests: [
            {input: 'D 096 H 094A15', expected: true}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Number 3',
        tests: [
            {input: '100 14-36-085-17W6 00', expected: true},
            {input: '200 D 096 H 094A15 00', expected: true},
            {input: '100 14-36-085-17W6', expected: false},
            {input: '14-36-085-17W6 00', expected: false}
        ]
    }
];
```

Let's try out our regexp. I'm just running these
tests in the developer console in Chrome (<kbd>F12</kbd> for that).

```
testcases.forEach(function(testcase){
    console.log(testcase.name);
    testcase.tests.forEach(function(test){
        var result = rx.test(test.input);
        console.log(test.input + '  result: ' +
                (result ? 'match' : 'no match') +
                (result === test.expected ? ' [pass]' : ' [**FAIL**]'));
    });
    console.log('');
});
```

And the output.

```
    Number 1
    14-36-085-17 W6  result: match [pass]
    14-36-085-17-W6  result: match [pass]
    14-36-085-17W6  result: match [pass]

    Number 2
    D 096 H 094A15  result: match [pass]

    Number 3
    100 14-36-085-17W6 00  result: match [pass]
    200 D 096 H 094A15 00  result: match [pass]
    100 14-36-085-17W6  result: no match [pass]
    14-36-085-17W6 00  result: no match [pass]
```

Great. Having tests gives you confidence to make changes,
and reassurance that you haven't broken anything when you
do. And it gives me confidence that I'm not giving you a
duff answer. If you search you'll see that there are many
automated unit testing frameworks available that will make
writing tests easier. What I've given you is a rudimentary
example. But the big win comes when you start running
automated tests at all; everything after that is refinement.

By the way, these tests are just the examples that you supplied
in the question as being valid or invalid (thanks for that!). I'd
recommend that you find some more examples and build on this.
Hopefully I've given you enough pointers that you'd be able
to take it from here if what I've done doesn't turn out to
be sufficient in any way.

This may seem a little over the top for a regexp answer, but
I can't recommend with a clear conscience that you use a huge
regexp for validation without also recommending some machinery
to keep things manageable.

---

*Further reading*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: Wow - this is much more than I was expecting. As you can probably tell, I'm no programmer, but I have to use javascript occasionally to validate things. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah, it's more than I was expecting too! But the more I thought about it the more I had to keep adding stuff. There are other good answers here now too (there weren't when I started writing, sorry!).

Answer (score 1):

`/^([1-2]0[0-9] )?[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}[- ]?W[0-9]( 0[0-9])?$/`

for the first one, and

`/^([1-2]0[0-9] )?[A-D] [0-9] [0-9]{3} [A-L] [0-9]{3}[A-P][0-9]{2}( 0[0-9])?$/`

for the second.  I'm not great with regex, so it's completely possible I messed something up somewhere.

Comment: This is great, thanks. But - the leading 3 and trailing 2 chars is an "all or nothing" thing.

Your pattern validates this: "100 14-36-085-17W6 00" but also "100 14-36-085-17W6" and "14-36-085-17W6 00"

only the first is correct

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement in your comment on @SamuelReid's answer, the regex will get ugly. It gets hard when two string requirements are dependent on each other being on/off (on opposite sides of the string).

#### The regex:

`/^(?:(?:[12]0\d (?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}) 0\d)|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}))$/`

#### Nicely formatted/easier to read version:

```
/^
  (?:
    (?:
      [12]0\d[ ]
      (?:
        \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d
        |
        [A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}
      )
      [ ]0\d
    )
    |
    (?:
      \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d
      |
      [A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}
    )
  )
$/x
```

(added `[]` around whitespaces to emphasize them, as they are important and lost in free-spacing mode (x flag) -- which AFAIK is not supported in js)

As you can see from the "easier to read version", the basic regex is just done twice with the added `[12]0\d[ ]` and `[ ]0\d` on one of the expressions.

[See it live on regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%2F%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%5B12%5D0%5Cd%20%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%5B%20-%5D%3FW%5Cd%7C%5BA-D%5D%20%5Cd%7B3%7D%20%5BA-L%5D%20%5Cd%7B3%7D%5BA-P%5D%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%200%5Cd%29%7C%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%5B%20-%5D%3FW%5Cd%7C%5BA-D%5D%20%5Cd%7B3%7D%20%5BA-L%5D%20%5Cd%7B3%7D%5BA-P%5D%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29%24%2F&input=14-36-085-17%20W6%0A14-36-085-17-W6%0A14-36-085-17W6%0AD%20096%20H%20094A15%0A100%2014-36-085-17W6%2000%0A200%20D%20096%20H%20094A15%2000%0A100%2014-36-085-17W6%0A14-36-085-17W6%2000)

---

If it needs to match in the middle of a string, simply swap out the `^` and `$` anchors with `\b` on both ends of the regex:

#### Regex with `\b` boundary instead of `^` and `$`

`/\b(?:(?:[12]0\d (?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}) 0\d)|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}))\b/`

Answer (score 1):

The first number type can be matched with the following expression, which is very similar to what you already have:

```
/d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d/
                       ^^^^^ 
                       added
```

I'm using the character set, `[- ]?`, which optionally matches a space or hyphen.

**The extra characters**

Matching the left:

```
/^[12]0\d /
```

And right part:

```
/ 0\d$/
```

All together now:

```
/^(?:(?:[12]0\d )(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2})(?: 0\d)|(?:\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[ -]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2}))$/
```

Let's clean that up a little:

```
var w1 = '\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}[ -]?W\\d',
w2 = '[A-D] \\d{3} [A-L] \\d{3}[A-P]\\d{2}',
words = '(?:' + w1 + '|' + w2 + ')',
prefix = '[12]0\\d ',
suffix = ' 0\\d',
re;

re = new RegExp('^(?:' + prefix + words + suffix + '|' + words + ')$');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the 5 additional digits mentioned in the question. 3 before and 2 after.

Comment: @ohaal Well, it's more of the journey than the destination I'd argue :)

Comment: That's pretty much what I've got, except you've used non-capturing groups whereas I didn't bother. Don't forget to escape the backslashes when you compose your regexps from strings though.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not all that bad (though definitely a big regex).  This should cover both patterns and the additional possible digits at the beginning or end.

Here's the pattern that you need:

```
var re = new RegExp("^([1-2]0\\d )?(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}[\- ]?W\\d|[A-D] \\d{3} [A-L] \\d{3}[A-P]\\d{2})( 0\\d)?$");
```

. . . or, alternately:

```
var re = /^([1-2]0\d )?(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2}[\- ]?W\d|[A-D] \d{3} [A-L] \d{3}[A-P]\d{2})( 0\d)?$/
```

The rest of your code should work fine with it.

**Edit:** Based on my new understanding of "all or nothing", I've updated my approach . . . I'd do two tests based off of two regex patterns constructed from common patterns.

```
var sCorePattern = "(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{2}[\- ]?W\\d|[A-D] \\d{3} [A-L] \\d{3}[A-P]\\d{2})";
var sSecondaryPattern = "[1-2]0\\d " + sCorePattern + " 0\\d";

var regCorePattern = new RegExp("^" + sCorePattern + "$");
var regSecondaryPattern = new RegExp("^" + sSecondaryPattern + "$");

if (regCorePattern.test(s) || regSecondaryPattern.test(s)) {
    . . . do stuff . . .
}
else {
    . . . do other stuff . . .
}
```

To me it's a good combination of efficiency and reuse, without sacrificing readability.   :)

Comment: You can't do that; if the first three characters are present, the last two must be present too.

Comment: Ooooooh . . . I misread the "all or nothing" part of it . . . I thought he meant "all or nothing" on each individual grouping of optional numbers.  Hmmmm . . .